# django 'Manager' object is not iterable (but the code works in the manage.py shell)

Tags: django, templates, exception

I'm new to django and created an application not much different from the polls website described in the tutorial.
In the website I get:

```
Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError
Exception Value:    
Caught TypeError while rendering: 'Manager' object is not iterable
Exception Location: /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py in render, line 190
```

pointing to the template marking the error lin line 4 (Caught TypeError while rendering: 'Manager' object is not iterable):

```
test
2   {% if clips %}
3       <ul>
4       {% for aclip in clips %}
5           <li><a href="/annotate/{{ aclip.id }}/">{{ aclip.name }}</a></li>
6       {% endfor %}
7       </ul>
8   {% else %}
9       <p>No clips are available.</p>
10  {% endif %}
```

Here is the clip object:

```
class Clip(models.Model):
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    url = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

And the view code:

```
def index(request):
    #return HttpResponse("You're looking at clips.")
    mylist = []
    latest_clip_list = Clip.objects.all()#.values_list("name","id")#.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
    print latest_clip_list
    return render_to_response('annotateVideos/index2.html', {'clips': latest_clip_list})
```

When I run this code from the manage,py shell there is no exception:

```
In [2]: from annotateVideos import views

In [3]: f = views.index("")
[{'id': 6L, 'name': u'segment 6000'}]

In [4]: f.content
Out[4]: 'test\n\n    <ul>\n    \n        <li><a href="/annotate//"></a></li>\n    \n        </ul>\n'
```

Any ideas?
I find it hard to debug as the code seems to be working on the shell but not on the web server.

Thanks,
Raphael

Comment: Can you post what the line `print latest_clip_list` outputs in the web logs on the server? Also, in the error page you are receiving, each line in the traceback should have a section you can expand to see the local variables in each stack frame. You can see what `latest_clip_list` contains in the view function from there.

Answer (score 33):

You have a lot of parts commented out in your view code, specifically in the line

```
latest_clip_list = Clip.objects.all()#.values_list("name","id")#.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
```

The error you are getting, `'Manager' object is not iterable`, would indicate that the for loop in your template is trying to iterate over the manager `Clip.objects`, and not the queryset `Clip.objects.all()`.

Double-check to make sure that your view actually reads

```
latest_clip_list = Clip.objects.all()
```

and *doesn't* just look like

```
latest_clip_list = Clip.objects
```

Comment: Double checked.
It also returns a list of objects in the manager.py shell.

Comment: Just to make clear, the code posted was indeed the code, this answer does not resolve the question.

Comment: No, the output that you say you got from the shell session doesn't match the view code that you posted, at the very least. It appears that you've been commenting parts of the line out in order to track down the issue. I wanted to check that the code running on the server really was what you though it was.

Comment: Also, if you've been editing code live on the server's filesystem, it may be worth restarting the web server, just in case what you are seeing is the response from a thread that still has the old code resident in memory.

Comment: Perfect this worked for me I was using  models.School.objects and it showed the same error and I have updated it with  models.School.objects.all() and it worked, Thanks!